# JavaFX 2 Linux Exception

Tags: java, linux, javafx-2

Worked on a JavaFX 2 application and while testing on linux i got:

```
:/tmp$ /opt/Oracle_Java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/java -jar MyAdessoNotificationTool.jar 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkTimer._startImpl(Ljava/lang/Runnable;I)J
                at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkTimer._startImpl(Native Method)
                at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkTimer._start(GtkTimer.java:24)
                at com.sun.glass.ui.Timer.start(Timer.java:69)
                at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.finishLaunching(QuantumToolkit.java:366)
                at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
                at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:89)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

any ideas what it is?

greetings
Kaito

Comment: Do you have GTK2.18+ installed?

Comment: hmm it was tested on a 1204 lts ubuntu
the program should work without any further installations

Comment: How did you package your program and create the jar?  Did you try to include any JavaFX libraries with your program?  See related [forum post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2584290) (no real resolution I think).  Does it work with a more modern Java version?